# How to wrap React router NavigateFunction?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I wish to wrap React router's navigate function so that I can do some customization...

Here is my attempt:

```
import { NavigateFunction, NavigateOptions, To, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"

export function useNavigateCustom(): NavigateFunction {

    const navigate = useNavigate()

    function standardNavigate(to: To, options?: NavigateOptions) {
        // Some customization
        navigate(to, options)
    }

    function deltaNavigate(delta: number) {
        // Some customization
        navigate(delta)
    }

    // What to return here to conform to NavigateFunction interface?
    return {
        ...(standardNavigate as NavigateFunction),
        ...(deltaNavigate as NavigateFunction),
    }
}
```

On the return statement I am getting error:

```
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'NavigateFunction'
```

For the reference, here is `NavigateFunction` definition:

```
export interface NavigateFunction {
    (to: To, options?: NavigateOptions): void;
    (delta: number): void;
}
```

Comment: Why do you spread the functions? Should be `return { standardNavigate , deltaNavigate }`

Comment: That was just an attempt suggested by chatGpt that does not work.

Comment: @Dusan in this case, the moral to learn is don't trust ChatGPT

Comment: Ok, so you want it to be callable with different arguments like an overload https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function overloading in javascript. You have to manually check the parameters.

Take at look at [function overloading in typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)

```
export function useNavigateCustom(): NavigateFunction {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function navigateFunction(to: To, options?: NavigateOptions);
  function navigateFunction(delta: number);
  function navigateFunction(toOrDelta: To | number, options?: NavigateOptions) {
    if (typeof toOrDelta === "number") {
      navigate(toOrDelta);
    } else {
      navigate(toOrDelta, options);
    }
  }

  return navigateFunction;
}
```